# How to unit test with Jasmine on multiple chained functions with returns?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following function:

```
/**
* filters array down to the given allowed keys
* @param {Object} data
* @param {String[]} allowedKeys
*/
$scope.filterData = function(data, allowedKeys) {
    return Object.keys(data)
        .filter(function(key) {
            return allowedKeys.includes(key);
        })
        .reduce(function(obj, key) {
            obj[key] = data[key];
            return obj;
        }, {});
};
```

that I want to create a unit test for and so far I have the following:

```
describe('$scope.filterData', function() { 
        //params
        var data = {
            key1: "value1",
            key2: "value2",
            key3: "value3"
        }
        var allowedKeys = ["key1", "key2"];
        //mockobject
        var $Object = jasmine.createSpyObj('Object', ['keys', 'filter', 'reduce']);

        it('should func', function() {

            $Object.keys.and.returnValue($Object);
            $Object.filter.and.returnValue($Object);
            $Object.reduce.and.returnValue($Object);

            $scope.filterData(data, allowedKeys);
            expect(Object.filter).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
```

The issue that I am having, is that I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'allowedKeys.includes(key)')

I do not understand, how to fix that error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't if this solution could help you or not
When we write test case, especially test for functions, we tend to test the input and output value for the function.
And for me, I think we shouldn't touch the primitive function of `Array, Object` by calling jasmine mock.
If you want to know if your function is working properly in this case.

For example:

```
describe('$scope.filterData', function() { 
    //params
    var data = {
        key1: "value1",
        key2: "value2",
        key3: "value3"
    }
    var allowedKeys = ["key1", "key2"];

    it('should return 2 key', function() {            
        var expected = {
          key1: "value1",
          key2: "value2",
        }

        var value = $scope.filterData(data, allowedKeys);
        expect(JSON.stringify(value)).toEqual(JSON.stringify());
    });
});
```

Of course we have to mock some functions sometimes, like when we have the http request and have to wait, or we have function from other places to use and want to mock them.
But in this case, your function is not really necessary for `expect` some function `to be called`, it's simply enough and don't depend on anything else.
So best we should only focus on the input and output values of function

Comment: You are missing the param in `JSON.stringify()`, it should be `JSON.stringify(expected)`, right?

Comment: yeah, it's my typo,should be JSON.stringify(expected)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `Object` does not have a function `filter`and your `jasmine.createSpyObj` is literally useless. As @Luan Phan says in his answer, we usually tend to test the input and output value for the function. Javascript built-in functions do not need to be tested in our tests.

But, if you would like to know, for example, if `Object.keys` was called inside your function, here is an example

```
it('should func', function () {                        
    spyOn(Object, 'keys').and.callThrough();

    $scope.filterData(data, allowedKeys);                     

    expect(Object.keys).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The same can be done for the rest of the built-in functions used in `filterData`

```
it('should func', function () {
    spyOn(Object, 'keys').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(Array.prototype, 'filter').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(Array.prototype, 'reduce').and.callThrough();

    $scope.filterData(data, allowedKeys);

    expect(Object.keys).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(Array.prototype.filter).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(Array.prototype.reduce).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

If you really need to *mock* what one of the built-in functions returns, here is an example

```
it('should func', function () {
    const mockResult = {};

    spyOn(Array.prototype, 'reduce').and.returnValue(mockResult);

    const result = filterData(data, allowedKeys);

    expect(result).toBe(mockResult);
});
```

Again, Javascript's built-in functions already have tests written in *some other place*, we don't need to test it in our test, our focus should be on the functions we write.

Hope it helps