# How can I mock onload function without ajax using jasmine framework

Tags: javascript, jasmine

*javascript file:*

```
const getDisplayNews = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?sources=al-jazeera-english&apiKey=**********************", true);
request.onload = () => {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        resolve(JSON.parse(request.response));
    } else if (request.status === 404) {
        reject("Error! Not Found");
    }
};
request.send();
```

});

I need to mock onload function here. I have done upto open function.
Here is the code:

```
describe("javascript  file", () => {
describe("The exposed displaynews function", () => {
    let resolveSpy;
    let rejectSpy;
    beforeEach(() => {
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype = jasmine.createSpyObj("XMLHttpRequestSpy", ["open"]);
    });
    it("returns a promise object", () => {
        expect(getDisplayNews()).toEqual(jasmine.any(Promise));
    });
    });
    it("should call proper API", () => {
        getDisplayNews();
        expect(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
            "GET", "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?sources=al-jazeera-english&apiKey=**************", true);
    });
```

How do I do it for onload function.

Thanks

Comment: You can use `spyOn(XMLHttpRequest.prototype, 'onload').and.returnValue(mockResponse)`. Check the examples in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51331618/how-to-unit-test-with-jasmine-on-multiple-chained-functions-with-returns/51334816#51334816), it is not about `XMLHttpRequest` but are using native objects.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on if you are unit testing or integration testing. For a simple unit test, There should also be 2 tests for both positive and negative response

You can do this by:

- Exporting your JS as a module
- Importing it in your test
- Faking the function and then dealing with the anticipated promise result

A stubbed out example should be something like:

```
it('Should Resolve', () => {
    spyOn(moduleName,'load').and.callFake(() => {
                 return 200;
    });
    expect(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.load).toBe(200);

})
   it('Should NOT Resolve', () => {
        spyOn(moduleName,'load').and.callFake(() => {
                     return 400;
        });
        expect(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.load).toBe(400);

    })
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i do that I am getting an error:<spyOn> : onload() method does not exist
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)

Comment: Did you make your `XMLHttpRequest` module correctly? Try commenting it out and running `typeof()` on it to make sure.

Comment: Yeah, added it to XMLHttpRequest , but even then it doesn't seems to be working